# auto run batch file windows in folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a question. I have created a batch file in windows, it resides in a folder and that folder will be receiving many files during the day. My question is...

Is there anyway to auto run a batch file every time a file is copied to a folder?

Comment: What mechanism is copying the files to the folder?

Comment: [Here's a commented hint](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/10/11/how-can-i-automatically-run-a-script-any-time-a-file-is-added-to-a-folder.aspx): use `__InstanceCreationEvent` and `CIM_DirectoryContainsFile` WMI class

Comment: You cannot do this without writing some code that registers with a filechangend-event. What I would do in this case is having the Windows Task Scheduler execute the script periodically (e.g. once per hour)